# FullCalendar Multiple Google calendars in an array

Tags: fullcalendar

The FullCalendar [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/) show the following for multiple Google calendars:

```
eventSources: [
            {
                googleCalendarId: 'abcd1234@group.calendar.google.com'
            },
            {
                googleCalendarId: 'efgh5678@group.calendar.google.com',
                className: 'nice-event'
            }
        ]
```

This does not work:

```
eventObject.push({
                googleCalendarId
            });
eventSources: [ eventObject ]
```

How do I turn this into an array that will show multiple google calendars that I would dynamically be able to add?

What does work is:

```
eventObject.push({
                id: eventId[i],
                title: name[i],
                start: startTime[i],
                end: endTime[i],
                description: evDes[i].description
            });
eventSources: 
            [
                { 
                    events: eventObject
                }
            ]
```

But this is not the same thing. Importantly, I want to be able to use both and have both the google calendar and the json source that I'm parsing out this way. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. So if I'm iterating through a list of google calendars, I would have this: (I'm using C# and MVC to get the list of calendars into the Javascript - that's what "model" refers to here)

```
CalendarId = model.data[i].calendar_source;
gcalObject.push({
    googleCalendarId: CalendarId,
```

And then, in the calendar init, I'd have this:
`eventSources: gcalObject,`

And then I can separately have events that do not come from a Google calendar in the regular events object:
`events: eventsObject`

So problem solved. Google calendar events go in `eventSources` and other events go in `events`. And `eventSources` sits at the same hierarchical level as `events`.